# Give $\ker(\phi)$ for $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z_7}$ such that $\phi(1)=4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Give $\ker(\phi)$  for $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z_7}$ such that $\phi(1) = 4$

So the generator of $\mathbb{Z}$ maps to $4$ and $\langle 4 \rangle = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ so it has order seven.

so $\ker(\phi) = 7\mathbb{Z}$ because every seventh element will map to the identity under the given map. Is that the correct reasoning?

Comment: Yes, the kernel is $7\Bbb Z$

Comment: What is the value of $phi(25) $ in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the map $\phi$ is surjective (since it's image will be a non-trivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_7$, and hence is all of $\mathbb{Z}_7$), and so the kernel is an index $7$ subgroup in $\mathbb{Z}$, but only $7\mathbb{Z}$ is such a subgroup.